# Condition equivalent to homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

I have been given a topology assignment to do over the weekend, but I'm starting to think that one problem is actually asking for the proof of a false statement. The question is, word for word:

"Let $(X, τ_1 )$ and $(Y,τ_2)$ be topological spaces. Show that $f : X → Y$ is a homeormorphism
if and only if it is continuous and there is a mapping $g : Y → X$ such that
$f\circ g = I_Y$ and $g\circ f = I_X$ ($I_X$ and $I_Y$ are identity maps)."

It is fairly simple to show that $f$ is bijective, and by the uniqueness of inverses that $g=f^{-1}$ which is also bijectve. However I am struggling to prove that $f^{-1}$ is continuous, and I'm starting to believe that for this statement to be true in general we require that $g$ is continuous as well. Normally I'd try find a counter example but I have a busy weekend and the assignment is due on Monday, so I don't want to waste anymore time on this question than necessary. Hence I'd be very grateful if someone could just confirm whether the statement I'm being asked to prove is actually true or not.

Comment: For a counterexample let $X=Y=\mathbb R$, let $\tau_2$ be the indiscrete topology and let $\tau_1\neq\tau_2$. Then $id:X\to Y$ is continuous and is its own inverse. But the inverse is not continuous.

Comment: @drhab What an elegant example thank you.Slightly embarrassing that I couldn't come up with it immediately, but I'll blame lack of sleep to save face.

Comment: Have a good night sleep! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. A homeomorphism can be defined as a continuous bijection with continuous inverse. Thus, the map $g$ must also be continuous.

Furthermore, continuity of $f$ is not enough to guarantee continuity of $g$, so it must be stated that $g$ is continuous.

As an example of a continuous bijection whose inverse is not continuous, consider the map $f:[0,2\pi)\to S^1,$ the unit circle in the plane, defined by $\theta\mapsto (\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$. There is a sequence of points $(z_n)$ on $S^1$ in the fourth quadrant that converges to $(1,0)$ from below, but the sequence $f^{-1}(z_n)$ converges to $2\pi$, not $f^{-1}(1,0) = 0$ as continuity requires.

This $f$ is a continuous bijection whose inverse fails to be continuous.

Comment: As I thought, thank you for saving my time :)

Comment: @K.Power see my updated answer for a counterexample.